# Как учитывать неразрывный пробел в тексте в push-нотификейшнах от gmail?

Tags: push-уведомления

Всем привет.

1. Отправляю письмо. 
   В письме html, например: "...Сумма доставки `1&nbsp;000` долларов...."
2. Письмо приходит получателю.

   2.1. У получателя на телефоне отображается push-нотификейшн, где "1" и "000" на разных строках (не верно).

   2.2. Но в браузере, в gmail неразрывный пробел отображается нормально ("1 000" не разбивается - все верно).

Может кто сталкивался с таким? Как решить проблему в пушах?

Comment: замените пробел на &nbsp;

Comment: Сейчас так и есть (в моем вопросе, в сумме, не отобразился &nbsp; - сейчас видно). Из клиента gmail все ОК. Проблема в пуше.